Qt designer: layout with a resizing plot, but controls with fixed size
Note, this is not the same as this question, which regards spacers and buttons being too large for their containing layout while resizing.
Instead, I want to set a fixed size to one of the direct children of a HLayout, to make it a non-resizing pane. I read here that I should rather control the size of the contained widgets, but that would be rather cumbersome, given the hierarchy of the pane that I want at constant width.
I am trying to create a window design, that features:

an animated plot on the right
a left pane with line edits, buttons.
the size of the plot changes with the size of the main window
the left pane has a fixed width and stays flush on the left.

I have tried multiple combinations of Layouts, Frames, Widgets, to no av. This is what I have now:

As expected, the plot_layout does not show in the preview, since there is no widget within. Fine.

Here is what happens when I resize the application window. Reasonable:

Wide controls, instead of wide plot, not so reasonable:

I suspect that this partially has to do with how I create the plot (it's a matplotlib plot, I use FigureCanvasQTAgg and add it plot_layout as a widget). But even so, I would like to fix the whole left pane's width, no matter the figure size.

You must set a main layout. The layouts on the widget box are intended for nested layouts (when adding a layout to another layout). Whenever you see that red icon near a widget, it means that it doesn't have a proper layout set. Remove those widgets from that "horizontalLayout" and delete it, then right click on an empty area (or on the "centralwidget" in the inspector) and select "Lay out horizontally" from the "Lay out" submenu. Then check the documentation about using layouts in Designer.

Note that you must also set a proper layout on "frame".

Thanks for that good feedback. I'm still struggling with the designer and layouts, but you helped. My question was closed as duplicate, but the referred question was not the same, working on opening it again. Your input might become irrelevant, sorry about that.

The duplicated post had a different result, but was primarily caused by the same problem (not using layouts appropriately). Note though that I won't vote for reopening, as the editing you introduced will probably result in a different duplicate closure. You have two possibilities: 1. set a proper layoutStretch value for the central widget (0,1 should be enough to ensure that the contents at the right will expand); 2. set an expanding size policy for the plot widget added by code (setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Preferred)).

Note that if you only add the plot widget on the right, then you don't need plot_layout at all: just add it to the central widget's layout() (which is already horizontal). Consider looking into "widget promotion", so that you'll be able to properly add a placeholder for the plotwidget, assuming it's a subclass of FigureCanvasQTAgg (you won't be able to "see" it as an actual plotwidget, but it will help you in visualizing the result and adjusting the overall layout. I also suggest you to do some basic tests with simple widgets in order to familiarize with Qt layouts and size management.

@musicamante I still don't get why the question is closed. I understand that the answer to that other question might help me figure it out, but the problem is not the same. As a matter of fact, I have now managed to create the design I was looking for (partly thanks to you, thanks), but I cannot post the solution. The pragmatic solution.

As said, even if we reopen it because the given duplicated doesn't match anymore the update, it will eventually be closed again because it will most certainly be a duplicate of another post. If you're completely sure that your solution would be unique, I suggest you to shortly explain in detail what you did (in a comment, don't add it to the question), eventually adding the solution to a pastebin; then we'll examine it and eventually vote for reopening (it already got one vote, but reopening needs 3). Alternatively, open a chat and we'll discuss it there.

I voted to reopen because, even if the solution might end up being similar, I don't see how the questions themselves relate to each other other than that they both involve resizing elements in Qt

This configuration works to achieve my goal:

